# 1.0 as boolean dtype cause ValueError in pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file similar to the following one where I want to read "boolean_column" as a nullable boolean dtype with pandas.

```
boolean_column, string_column
1.0, a
0.0, b
,c
```

When I read it with using `pd.read_csv()` without assigning dtypes, no error is raised:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

example_csv = """
boolean_column, string_column
1.0, a
0.0, b
,c"""

csv = io.StringIO(example_csv)
df = pd.read_csv(csv)
df.info()

>>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   boolean_column  2 non-null      float64
 1    string_column  3 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

However, I want "boolean_column" to have a nullable boolean dtype instead of float64. Therefore, I assign a dtype when reading the data.

```py
csv = io.StringIO(example_csv)
df = pd.read_csv(csv, dtype={"boolean_column": "boolean"})

>>> ValueError: 1.0 cannot be cast to bool
```

I think it is more elegant to immedeatly assign the correct dtype instead of casting the float64 afterwards. What am I not getting? This should work, right?

At least this does:

```py
pd.Series([None, 1.0, 0.0]).astype("boolean")

>>> 0     <NA>
1     True
2    False
dtype: boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with an out-of-the-box feature of `read_csv` that solved this. You can, however, build your own converter:

```
def foo(x):
    if x == "1.0": 
        return True
    elif x == "":
        return np.NaN
    else:
        return False

pd.read_csv(StringIO(example_csv), converters = {"boolean_column": foo})
```

The result is:

```
  boolean_column  string_column
0           True              a
1          False              b
2            NaN              c
```

Comment: Does that answer your question?